# Image that I inserted is not displaying; shows filepath only instead with no compile error

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I am currently writing notes using Overleaf for one of self-paced course and noticed that I can't seem to display the image correctly, despite having identical code from documentation. My current code is following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

...

\begin{document}

...

\subsection{The Internet}
Structure of the internet can be defined as following:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mobile Network
    \item National/Global ISP
    \item Local/Regional ISP
    \item Home Network
    \item Enterprise Network

    Above five parts are the main components that makes up the network. \textit{Figure 1} Represents how each of these parts are related. 
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{{Chapter1/NetworkStruct}}
    \caption{Overall structure of network.}
    \label{fig:Unit 1}
\end{figure}

...

\end{document}
```

Where ellipses indicate information that is not directly related to this issue. My current output is following:

[image: Semantic Error where it compiles but does not show image.]

I looked at previous troubleshooting threads, but it seems that they're using different TeX editor that directly imports from their machine while I uploaded imagine online. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Chapter1/NetworkStruct}`?

Comment: as cfr hints you have spurious doubled `{{` here `{{Chapter1/NetworkStruct}}`

Comment: According to Overleaf documentation, Overleaf needs double curly brackets to import image from file path. 

This is what I have been referencing to for now (under 'folder path to images'):
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Inserting_Images#The_folder_path_to_images

Comment: there is nothing on that page that I see that says to double the argument braces for `\includegraphics` It is not guaranteed to work with doubled braces (in fact it will generally fail)

Answer (score 5):

Just solved the issue... turns out, I was using "Fast[draft]" mode to prevent rendering the image for fast compile, so there is nothing wrong with what I was doing.... Here is the link that I referenced to solve this:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Images_not_showing_up

Comment: So the sample code you supplied was incorrect?

Comment: @HerbSchulz There was nothing wrong with what I provided. Issue was that there's an setting in Overleaf where you can toggle to have "Normal" and "Fast" viewer. In "fast" mode, it does not render image to speed up compilation process. Please refer to link that I have posted for more detail.